# MATLAB function for filling in doughnut

Tags: matlab, octave

Is there a fancy MATLAB function for filling in a doughnut?  I am having problems with the following two functions merging the doughnut with the junk near by.

```
 image = bwmorph(image,'close');
 image = bwmorph(image,'dilate');
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you want the output to be? Do you want to fill the hole, or color the doughnut itself?

Comment: Filling in a donut? I did a search for jelly.m, no go. Then I tried custard.m, it too is missing in MATLAB. Drat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filling with `imfill`. Given your binary image is called `m`, ry

```
locations= sub2ind(size(m), 100, 80);
m2 = imfill(m,locations);
```

[image]

Bon Appétit